# Tracking/recovery options for ChromeBook

Tags: google-chrome-os, anti-theft, chromebook

On my Android and Windows-based laptop, I use a product called [Prey](http://preyproject.com/) that lets me track, lock-down, and (hopefully) recover my device should it ever be stolen.

They have options for Android, Windows, Mac, and several flavors of Linux.

However, I have a third device I'd like to protect: My Chromebook.

Prey, obviously, isn't going to work for that. What are my options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I was searching for a similar option online, for the Chromebook and came across this,it is worth a read.
[Google Chrome - Chromebook Locator](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=72875383cf010240&hl=en)

The only such product available according to my knowledge is "Laptop Lookout". This is the only one available in the Chrome Web Store. 
Check the official website of it also.

[Laptop Lookout](http://laptoplookout.com)

Comment: Wow. I'm disappointed at the lack of options out there.